# django objects.create method is too slow How to make faster?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

multiple tables are mapped and, when I create post request,

it takes about 2~3 seconds. Is there any ways to fix it?

I guess it takes a long time on:

1. objects.create
2. for loop
3. product.objects.get

however, I am not able to find the better ways..

models:

#product, Order, OrderItems, ShippingAddress are mapped

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paid_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    is_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True)   
    shipping_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True)   
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True) 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
    
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    
    def image_preview(self):
        if self.image:
            return mark_safe('<img src="{0}" width="55" height="55" />'.format(self.image))
        else:
            return '(No image)'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)


class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

view:

```
@permission_classes(IsAuthenticated)
@api_view(['POST'])
def OrderCreate(request):
    data = request.data
    user = request.user
    order_items = data['orderItems']
    #1.create order
    order = Order.objects.create(
        user = user,
        total_price = data['totalPrice'],
        shipping_price = data['shippingPrice'],
        payment_method = data['paymentMethod']
    )
    
    #2.create orderItems 
    for i in order_items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=i['id'])
        
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            order = order,
            product = product,
            name = i['name'],
            qty = i['qty'],
            price = i['price'],
            image = i['image']
        )
        
        #3. update stock
        product.stock -= i['qty']
        product.save()
        
    #4.create shipping address
    
    shipping_address = ShippingAddress.objects.create(
    user = user,
    order = order,
    address = data['shippingAddress']['address'],
    city = data['shippingAddress']['city'],
    postal_code = data['shippingAddress']['postalCode'],
    country = data['shippingAddress']['country'],
        
    )

    #5.serializing and save

    serializer = OrderSerializer(order, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Accessing the database within a for loop is not a good idea. You can replace the lines `product = Product.objects.get(id=i['id'])` and `product.save()` in your view function for loop with a `Q` filters and a `bulk_update` respectively and get rid of the for loop.

Comment: can you share this list of data `order_items` im confused about structure.

Comment: @henrikstroem yeah now I understand that for loop is not a good idea I am looking for bulk_update thanks

Comment: @HemalPatel order_items contains data for OrderItem table, for example, {order=3, product=15,name: macbook, qty: 1, price: 2000}

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate the order_items without ever fetching the product,  provided you have sufficient trust for the product ids in `i['id']`

```
for i in order_items:
    # product = Product.objects.get(id=i['id'])
    
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
        order = order,
        product_id  = i['id'],   # set the id (magic suffix) without fetching product
        name = i['name'],
        qty = i['qty'],
        price = i['price'],
        image = i['image']
    )
```

Instead of using `.create` you might instantiate these order_items as a list of unsaved instances and create them using `OrderItem.bulk_create` Read the [bulk_create documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create); it has a number of caveats.

You could then run a loop updating the product stock field using an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to subtract from the current value in the product row without actually fetching a product object from the DB

```
for i in order_items:
    product_id = i['id']
    Product.objects.filter(
         pk = product_id
    ).update(
         stock = F('stock') - i['qty']
    )
```

If you do fetch all the product instances into a list with updated stock values, there's also `bulk_update` which would let you apply all the updated stock values in a single DB operation. This might be better than doing them one by one with an F expression. You can also fetch them in bulk using

```
Product.objects.filter( pk__in=[ i['id'] for i in order_items ] )
```

(Warning, I don't think that there's any guarantee that the queryset contains the objects in the same order that you supply the i['id'] values )

Treat this as brainstorming. I'm not entirely certain that this is correct and I really don't know whether it will speed things up a lot, a little, or at all. I'd be interested to know, if you try it.

Comment: I fixed my code according to your advise, bulk_create and F expression reduced query time 5.8sec to 3.8sec thanks a lot. Can I have one more question? If I use bulk_update instead of F expression, it it going to help to shorten the time bit more?

Comment: yes you can fetch all the `product_ids` in one list and then create another `list of objects` which are going to get created Using` bulk_create` but all you have care that you have to maintain `product_id and other respective product data` while creating `orderItem`

Comment: @HemalPatel thanks I tried bulk_upadate and transaction.atomic() with F expression instead of for loop to update the product stock and compared the result, tranction.atomic() took 0.8~1sec to get the result no matter how many items added. I think for loop took a huge time.. thank a lot